# Making it easier for users to fill out form on mobile apps

Tags: forms, mobile, mobile-application, data-entry, banking

I am working on a mobile app and we are experiencing significant dropoff when asking users to add their bank account details. The form is quite long but unfortunately these fields are mandatory. It would be great if someone could give some advice as to how to make this form easier to fill in for our users.

The fields we ask for are:

- Account holder name
- Country of bank account (drop down list)
- Currency of bank account (drop down list)
- IBAN/Account number (this is probably the main pain point as IBAN's in particular can be up to 30 characters long, which are difficult to enter on a mobile device)
- SWIFT/BIC/Sort Code (Pre-populated once the user provides correct IBAN)
- Bank Name (Pre-populated once the user provides correct IBAN/Account Number)
- Bank Address (Pre-populated once the user provides correct IBAN/Account Number)
- Additional Info (Optional)

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Could you share pictures of what you have now and/or what you have came up with.

Answer (score 4):

The dropoff you experience may not necessarily be attributed to the form itself, but rather a users reluctance to enter banking details at all. Does the user feel safe handing over these details, have you proven your trustworthiness? I think these are important questions to ask, and ensure you do everything you can to provide assurance (eg. any certification you have).

Onto the form itself. I notice 3 of the inputs are pre-populated from the users input. In this case, how about initially only displaying the top 4 inputs?

1. Name: This is user input, although you may be able to pull it from account details if applicable?
2. Country: dropdown, but could pre-populate from device settings.
3. Currency: dropbox, but pre-populate from previous Country setting.
4. IBAN. User input, ensure you provide the user with a number pad by default. If you have the resources, you could have a 'scan' function to scan a printed number with device camera.

Once these inputs are complete, the following 3 inputs could animate in, pre-populated with data for the user to check over. Including a helpful message, 'We've filled this in from what you've told us, is this correct?' would help the user understand the process. If all is good, all they have to do is tap a button to proceed.

The concept behind this solution; a user will feel that 4 inputs, 2 which are dropdown and even pre-populated, is a lot less to handle than a whole screen of unfamiliar terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app is for a reasonably well known/trusted company but you're correct, we could put the users mind more at ease with regards security. First we ask for a/c holder name, country and currency (pre-populating these where possible). These 3 fields drive whether we ask for IBAN/Account Number/Sort Code next. The final 4 fields only appear when the user provides the IBAN/Account Number and are pre-populated depending on the users input. Making an assumption here, but I feel the biggest pain point is entering the IBAN (up to 30 characters). Any tips for making this easier?

Comment: @obloblaw - a couple things that ensure IBAN entry is easy: - ensure 'paste' is allowed and enable voice dictation. You could implement a 'scanning' system to allow the user to use their device camera. On a simpler level, ensure you give the user plenty of reassurance that they are entering the correct number, so they don't have to do it more than once. Is there a common IBAN format you can 'predict'? Eg. first 4 letters etc. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple!

**Before you start finalising an approach**, I would suggest you invest in a tool like [VWO](https://vwo.com/) to analyze the form first.

We have implemented it on our product and I get to see exactly which field is causing issues and **where the users are getting lost**. **Interaction Time/ Hesitation Time**/ etc would give you the best idea about these.

> **USE SMART DEFAULTS!!!**

1. Can you ask just the IBAN number first? This might help you fill
   **Country/Currency/Swift/BankName/BankAddress**
2. Next, Ask his name and Submit

Remember to show **progress and feedback**. Explicit **placeholders** and **Error states**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We try to pre-populate any info where possible. We can't ask for IBAN first as the currency & country define whether we ask for an IBAN or Account Number next. Adding a progress tracker is a good idea, thanks. As I mentioned in the comment above, I believe that the adding of the IBAN (up to 30 characters) is the biggest pain point. Any tips to making this easier? We toyed with the idea of allowing the user to scan their IBAN from a bank statement but that was a non-runner.

Answer (score 0):

This is very big issue I face when my bank ask me to fill bunch of feilds. I really don't like that.

If I have to do some changes in that form which bank asked me to fill I would ask them, what all data you will found if I give my Swift Code, there is possible that after providing swift code, the bank name and address they may get it.

What I want to convey by above example is it is better to work on **auto-completion**.

Ask the user some details (one or two) which helps you to fill rest of the feilds automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Could it also be that users do not know where to find their IBAN number or have to leave the app/exit session to go look for the number?

Am facing the same problem because our form requires information that users may not have on hand. We try to mitigate that by stating upfront, the information they need to input and also where to find it e.g. look for your bank account number on your cheque etc.